# Implode multiple inputs

Tags: input, implode

I've got input like this:

```
<div id="fruit1">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Apple" />
    <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div id="fruit2">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Blackberry" />
    <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="4" />
</div>
<div id="fruit3">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Banana" />
    <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="1" />
</div>
```

Is there a simple way using implode to get result like this (single line):

```
Apple;2|Blackberry;4|Banana;1|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try this code :

```
$display = "";
$ctr = 0;
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $data) :
    $display .= $data.";".$_POST['qty'][$ctr]."|";
    $ctr++;
endforeach;

echo $display;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It count every $_POST I have. Let say I have input other than what I need to implode. Sorry for bad english. Can you change $_POST to get specific value?

Comment: Hi, sorry got some mistakes with the previous code. Try the code above again.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a LOT! Works perfectly!
Sorry, i wish can add you +1 Rep.